# Alguém tem uma dica de como validar uma permissão em uma controller

Tags: php

Alguém tem uma dica de como validar uma permissão em uma controller, permissão simples de liberar ou bloquear o usuário naquela controller, no momento só valido se o usuário está logado.

```
public function __construct()
{

    parent::__construct();


    if (!$this->session->userdata('logged')) {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect(base_url("login"));
    }


    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('Cadastro_m', 'cada_m');
}
```

Comment: Não pode usar a mesma lógica que usa para logar o usuário, mas com os parâmetros desejados para essa nova validação?

Comment: Não intendi amigo.

Comment: Eu entendi que para que o usuário esteja logado, exista uma lógica que vai dizer se ele tem ou não permissão para acessar áreas exclusivas à aqueles que estão logados, essa mesma lógica não poderia ser reaproveitada?

Comment: Hum intendi vou dar uma olhada valeu amigo.